# Using awk to print characters of specific index on a line

Tags: awk

Alright, so I know it is quite simple to print specific arguments of a line using $:

```
$ cat file
hello world

$ awk '{print $1}' file
hello
```

But what if I want to print chars 2 through 8? or 3 through 7? Is that possible with awk?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

```
awk '{print substr($0,2,6)}' file
```

the syntax for substr() is

`substr(string,start index,length)`

Comment: Why is the  field separator `-F='\n'` necessary? Or is it?

Comment: @Levon as i thought the OP wants to find the substring of the whole record, not the field.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, not trying to argue, just to get this straight for myself. `$0` is already the whole current line, so if you are taking substrings of the current whole line, I don't see why you'd have to specify `-F` .. what am I missing here?

Comment: @Levon oops! Thanks for pointing it out. :)
editing the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can use `substr` function :

http://www.starlink.rl.ac.uk/docs/sc4.htx/node38.html

In your case - for print chars from 2 through 8:

```
echo "hello" | awk '{ print substr( $0, 2, 6 ) }'
```

result is:

> ello

Answer (score 2):

If Perl is an option:

```
perl -lne 'print substr($_,1,6)' file
```

Output is identical to answer from @nims

Comment: I downvoted because the question is about awk, not Perl.