# unix: Using grep or awk - need to find occurrence of a letter on specific field print the line

Tags: unix

I have several fixed files and need to quickly scan them for occurrence of letter L on field 159 and print. 
Example:

```
123456ABCDEF23253657LA00000000MMMKSNS
123456ABCDEF23253657BA00000000MMMKSNS
123456ABCDEF23253657LA00000000MMMKSNS
123456ABCDEF23253657LA00000000MMMKSNS
12345        3253657LA00000000MMMKSNS
```

I tried `grep -E '^.{21} L'` but doesn't find for a 180 fixed length `grep -E '^.{159} L'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With awk you can print the substring. See [nim's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11401139/6020034) answer for syntax.

```
while read line; \
  do echo "$line" | awk '{print substr($0,21,1)}'| \
  grep -q "L"; [ $? -eq 0 ] && \
  echo "$line"; \
  done < "${file}"
```

**Output:**

```
123456ABCDEF23253657LA00000000MMMKSNS
123456ABCDEF23253657LA00000000MMMKSNS
123456ABCDEF23253657LA00000000MMMKSNS
12345        3253657LA00000000MMMKSNS
```

Answer (score 1):

You were very close,

```
echo "123456ABCDEF23253657LA00000000MMMKSNS
123456ABCDEF23253657BA00000000MMMKSNS
123456ABCDEF23253657LA00000000MMMKSNS
123456ABCDEF23253657LA00000000MMMKSNS
12345        3253657LA00000000MMMKSNS" | grep -E '^.{20}L'
```

**output**

```
123456ABCDEF23253657LA00000000MMMKSNS
123456ABCDEF23253657LA00000000MMMKSNS
123456ABCDEF23253657LA00000000MMMKSNS
12345        3253657LA00000000MMMKSNS
```

Note that having a space between `{20} L` throws off the position, AND that as your `L` is in Position 21, you skip `20` chars.

IHTH